# Complex and convoluted templating

Tags: c++, templates

So lets begin with my problem defination:

I have super large switch statement that I only want to define once. Each case in the switch statement will then call a templated function

I.E:

```
switch(whatever)
{
   case whatever::one:
      dosomething<char>(parameterone, parametertwo); breakl
   case whatever::two:
      dosomething<int>(parameterone, parametertwo); break;
   ... 
 }
}
```

This works perfectly. But lets say I want to complicate things. Specifically, I want the case statement to call two functions, i.e either do something or super-cool something.

I.E:

```
template<typename F>
void wrapper(parameterone, parametertwo)
{
  switch(whatever)
  {
   case whatever::one:
      F<char>(parameterone, parametertwo); break;
   case whatever::two:
      F<int>(parameterone, parametertwo); break;
   ... 
  }
 }
}
```

Where F is some sort of function pointer. Then I would call the wrapper function something like this:

```
wrapper<dosomething>(...);
```

OR

```
wrapper<superdosomething>(..);
```

(NOTE: I REALY DONT WANT TO DUPLICATE THE SWITCH STATEMENT FOR EVERY VALID FUNCTION FOR F)

Comment: Do you have control over the things you want to pass as template arguments to `wrapper`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a wrapper can be written. I will use a layer of delegation which might need to be adapted based on your real code.

```
template <class F>
void wrapper(param1, param2)
{
  switch (whatever)
  {
    case whatever::one:
      F::call<char>(param1, param2);
      break;

    case whatever::two:
      F::call<int>(param1, param2);
      break;
  }
}


struct DoSomething
{
  template <class T>
  static void call(param1, param2) { /* your code */ }
};


struct DoSomethingSuperCool
{
  template <class T>
  static void call(param1, param2) { /* your super-cool code */ }
};
```

Usage:

```
wrapper<DoSomething>(p1, p2);
wrapper<DoSomethingSuperCool>(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly you do not want to have F as a function but rather as a class. Such class could be a template class, possibly with partial or full specializations (it is much easier to make template specializations for a class than to a function).

Other details are less certain. The class can have a bunch of static functions, e.g. ProcessOne, ProcessTwo, etc., to be called in specific switch clauses. If class has a state, they should be non-static or even virtual. Implementation inheritance would allow you to make the code relatively compact.

Typically, huge switch statement is an indicator of not-so-good design and most often can be replaced with other types of dispatch, e.g. with virtual functions.